# How to implement binary search in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, binary

I have a table called Incentive. There are 4 columns in my table. I need to get the incentive amount for the input value combinations.

Example:

```
| State | Type   | Client | Website    | Amount |
| ----- | ----   | ------ | -------    | ------ |
| NJ    | 0      | 0      | google.com | 10     |
| 0     | 0      | CA     | google.com | 3      |
| NJ    | 0      | US     | google.com | 10     |
| NJ    | Typing | US     | google.com | 15     |
```

My Input is State=NJ, Type=Drawing, Client=US AND website = google.com

Here first I check all the four columns with my table columns and there is no matching found.

Then I check it with my first three columns of my table, then second three....like

```
WHERE State = NJ AND Type = Drawing AND Client = US
WHERE Type = Drawing AND Client = US AND website = google.com
WHERE State = NJ AND Client = US AND website = google.com
```

and so...

My expected output is 10 for the above input.

If there is no matching for three column combinations...then move into to the two columns. Like

```
WHERE State = NJ AND Type = Drawing
WHERE Type = Drawing AND Client = US
WHERE Client = US AND website = google.com
```

If there is no matching for two column combos...then move into to the one columns. Like

```
WHERE State = NJ
WHERE Type = Drawing
WHERE Client = US
WHERE website = google.com
```

If there is no match, then returns 0.

I already writes the query with the above mentioned method. But there are too much of lines of queries. And also in future if I added a new column to the table then it also increases the lines of queries and execution time.

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: What do you mean by "binary implementation" and _why_ do you need that? Can't you just use a `SELECT.. WHERE...`?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `check all the possible scenarios for getting the correct incentive amount`? Please elaborate with examples

Comment: So why doesn't `WHERE A=0 AND B=0 AND C=0 AND D = 5` do what you need? Where does "binary" come into it? Give an example of the "else check all the possible scenarios for getting the correct incentive amount"

Comment: @ndc85430 If there is 4 match then returns the relevant amount, else check with all the three column combinations like ABC, ABD, BCD....if not matching with 3 matches then need to match with 2 column combinations....like checking all these combinations till i need to get my amount.

Comment: @Squirrel  If there is 4 match then returns the relevant amount, else check with all the three column combinations like ABC, ABD, BCD....if not matching with 3 matches then need to match with 2 column combinations....like checking all these combinations till i need to get my amount.

Comment: @MartinSmith I need amount 4 here.  If there is 4 match then returns the relevant amount, else check with all the three column combinations like ABC, ABD, BCD....if not matching with 3 matches then need to match with 2 column combinations....like checking all these combinations till i need to get my amount.

Comment: You keep repeating the same thing without explaining what that means. Give actual examples, because nobody is understanding this

Comment: Probably you need to add a ranking column, then sort by that and take the `TOP (1) WITH TIES` which gets you all results with the top ranking value http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e84d4d/1

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks a lot, will try it and get back.